Why is there a 12GB+ disparity between (almost) same capacity drives with (almost) same content?
I have 2 drives (different brands) of approx. 2TB each. One holds video files for my home media server while the other is a mirror. While there is a small actual size disparity, a small amount of extra data, as well as one of the drives having a 200MB partition (from an old install that I forgot about), there is a disk use difference of around 12GB between df and du which I cannot account for.
Below are the drives in question (from lsblk):
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   200M  0 part 
└─sdc2   8:34   0   1.8T  0 part /home/das/ftpLinks/MoviesLink
                                 /mnt/2000plexserver
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/2000plexbackup

Below is a table showing the data disparity:



[KB]
size (df)
use (df)
free (df)
du
du --apparent




server
1953247232
1947318272
5928960
1935989376
1935340575


mirror
1953479676
1935552116
17927560
1935140538
1935123877


diff
232444
11766156
11998600
848838
216698



As you can see, the extra partition and the additional data together can account for approx 1GB of space difference, but not 12GB. Also i did du --apparent-size in hops of catching space caught up due to fragmentation etc., but doesn't help.
The only difference I have been able to see is the sector size (with fdisk -l):
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.82 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk model: BUP Slim        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D818BBF9-1C4A-4F23-A453-4D0A35087C53

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      40     409639     409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdc2  411648 3907028991 3906617344  1.8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdd: 1.82 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 2626
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 18083DF3-4BE4-4150-870D-85A2D903BF3C

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 3906961407 3906959360  1.8T Microsoft basic data

Any clues as to how I can figure this out?
EDIT1:
Filestystems: /sdc is exfat and /sdd is ntfs.
find '/mnt/2000plexserver/' -iname "*" | wc -l returns 10511 in the one with less space and 10503 in the other. But this difference is explained by the number of empty folders.
I know it's ugly. I didnt think I would use it longterm, but servarr happened.
Output of df -iT:
Filesystem     Type       Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs     2034695   1568   2033127    1% /run
/dev/sda2      ext4     11386880 479841  10907039    5% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2034695      1   2034694    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     2034695      3   2034692    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1      vfat            0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sde1      fuseblk 318835944 918014 317917930    1% /mnt/1000backupserver
/dev/sdc2      exfat           0      0         0     - /mnt/2000plexserver
tmpfs          tmpfs      406939     25    406914    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1      fuseblk  18058632  11064  18047568    1% /mnt/2000plexbackup

EDIT2:
The difference is probably due to one drive being exFAT vs the other being NTFS as pointed out by @Jaromanda X. More details in this linked answer.

"Microsoft basic data" - what filesystem are you using on those partitions? How many files do you have?

Add output from df -iT

@user10489 added in Edit1.

@JaromandaX "find '/mnt/2000plexserver/' -iname "*" | wc -l" returns 10511 in the one with less space and 10504 in the other. the difference is exactly equal to the number of empty folders.

OK .... so, exfat vs ntfs - not even the same filesystem, so. Research the difference

I see. Found an answer explaining the difference as mainly being due to different default cluster sizes between the two.
Thank you.

duplicate: Same files have different "size on disk" on new drive
